# Solr - Matching all provided user tokens

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

Enviornment ==> solr - solr-8.9.0, java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS

Following .csv file is indexed in solr

```
books_id,cat,name,price,inStock,author,series_t,sequence_i,genre_s
0553573403,book,Game Thrones Clash,7.99,true,George R.R. Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573404,book,Gam Thrones,7.99,true,George Martin,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573405,book,Throne Game,7.99,true,George,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
0553573406,book,Game Thrones Swords,7.99,true,George,"A Song of Ice and Fire",1,fantasy
```

I want to fuzzy-search for a book with having a name saying 'Game Thrones'.

field-type : text_general is configured for fields :'name' with multivalued as false. 'text_general' is using 'solr.StandardTokenizerFactory' as a tokenizer class in 'managed-schema'.

Output shall contain only these book-ids :

```
0553573404 : (name - Gam Thrones) 
0553573405 : (name - Throne Game)
```

I expect the following book ids not to match:

```
0553573403 (name - Game Thrones Clash) ==> 'Clash' is extra tokens, so it should not come in output. 
0553573406 (name - Game Thrones Swords) ==> 'Swords' is extra tokens, so they should not come in output.
```

Only the tokens specified in the input query are fuzzy-matched.

I understand that I can use the operator 'AND' in solr-query.
I've tried playing with a query that fuzzy-matches(input: 'Game Thrones') 'Game' as well as 'Thrones', but it is giving other results ('Game Thrones Clash'(books_id:0553573403) and 'Game Thrones Swords'(books_id:0553573406)).

To do this following query is executed

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/testCore2/select --data-urlencode "q=(name:'Game~') AND (name:'Thrones~')"
```

But the above query is giving all book-ids in the result.(0553573403,0553573404,0553573405,0553573406)

How can i find-out indended results in solr-query?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view it will not work as you expected.

You can try with 2 separate fields for this.

The first field with non tokenized one, you can use either string fieldtype or use textfield type with `KeywordTokenizerFactory` with `LowerCaseFilterFactory`.

The second field should be with tokenized one, here you may user `StandardTokenizerFactory` or any other like `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` depending upon your requirement.

You will have to search on the non tokenized field when you want the fuzzy search or exact match.

You can also try with Proximity search.

`Proximity Searches` : The syntax of a proximity search is by appending the tilde symbol ~ and a numeric value to the end of a search phase. It matches terms within a specific distance (the number of term movements needed) from one another. For example:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8983/solr/testCore2/select --data-urlencode "q=\"Game Thrones\"~1"
```